# python call vim open multiple files

Tags: python, vim, call

I'm trying to call vim from a python script to open multiple files.

```
files = []
for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    files.append(i)

string = " ".join(str(x) for x in files)
call(["vim", string])
```

when I call `./open.py 11 42 39` it only open one file called "11 42 39".

How to open them as separates files ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the seperate files as seperate items in your list:

```
call(["vim"] + files)
```

That is because when you pass a list, then each element in the list after the first one is given to vim as a seperate argument. So you are just giving vim the argument `"11 42 39"`. The argument will **not** be split at " " into three seperate arguments.

If you want to see all files at the same time you can also add `-o` to the call to vim:

```
call(["vim", "-o"] + files)
```

Comment: And if you want to see all the files at the same time, you can add -o/-O flags:


vim -o/-O <FILES_LIST>

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you, I'll add it to the answer